# Trying to show the data from my local api through an onclick function wont work, what's the solution?

Tags: javascript, html, express

I am trying to fetch some local data from my api and post it on the browsers console using a button however it doesnt work when in the button's function but it works perfectly fine when it is outside the onclick function, i even tried  a return statement for the fetch. I am trying to do so, so i can display all the data on an html table generated by JS. Anyways here is the html code followed by the JS code :

```
function getUsers(){
return fetch('http://localhost:3000/users')
.then(response => response.json())
.then(json => console.log(json))
}
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-outline-light" onclick="getUsers()">Users</button>
```

js code :

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
var cors = require('cors');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
//server stuff end

const xlsx = require('xlsx');
const file = xlsx.readFile('./testing.xlsx');
const sheet = file.Sheets['Sheet1'];
const content = xlsx.utils.sheet_to_json(sheet);
//reading xlsx file from sheet 1

app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(cors()); //using cors so we can call it from html file

app.get('/', function (req, res) {
 })


app.get('/Users', function (req, res) {
res.send(content);
})


app.listen(3000);
```

Comment: You don't need bodyParser, you can use `app.use(express.json())`

Comment: If you add the right tag to your question for 'express' or whatever it is, you'll probably get more responses.

Comment: also, it looks like youre requesting /users and not /Users.

Comment: Same thing about users and Users

Answer (score 0):

Could you please describe what "doesnt work" means? Is the onclick()-Function placed at the right position in code, what does your developer console tells you when clicking the button and have you tried a simple console.log statement in the onclick()-function to evaluate if it is fired at all?

I tried the code (with my own url) and it worked as expected.

Comment: well nothing would show on the console however it would work outside the function